# Django Pre-defined groups

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to create a group model with permissions already estabilished? I'm trying to create a system with at least 4 pre defined user types, and each user type will have some permissions.

Comment: You can create groups pretty easily in the admin panel. Will this be suitable for your needs?

Comment: No, @gtlambert. I want to have theese groups already created when a I start my application... There is some whey to achieve that?

Comment: @RodrigoAraújoValente Yes you can create your fixtures. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/

Answer (score 0):

Yes just create your desired groups in admin panel and add your permissions to each group then assign your users to the defined groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Group and Permissions creating commands to a migration, using the RunPython operation.